# How to query a record that has many assoiated rows in onother table to be viewed as one row

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a `wp_posts` table:

```
id
post_title
post_status
post_type
```

and `wp_postmeta` table:

```
meta_id
post_id
meta_key
meta_value
```

I want to query this tables to reprented as:

```
post_id |     a_meta_key_from_postmeta_col             | another_meta_key
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    |    value_of_the_meta_key_assotated           | value_of_the_other_key_assotated_with_this_post
   2    |    ......                                    | ...
```

```
SELECT wp_posts.id, wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value 
FROM `wp_posts` 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.id=wp_postmeta.post_id 
WHERE wp_posts.post_type='foo' 
AND post_status='publish' 
AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key='some_key' 
OR wp_postmeta.meta_key='another_some_key';
```

This the result

```
id     | meta_key         | meta_value
 1     | some_key         | some_value
 1     | another_key      | another_value
 2     | some_key         | some_value
 ...   | ...              |   ...
```

This not what I want.

(My ultimate goal is to export this to an csv file)

Comment: Please show what you DO want. Not a vague generalisation; give some concrete example data with the exact results you need to export from that concrete example.

Comment: @MIA did you check my solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export to csv file you should use `into outfile` statement.

```
SELECT wp_posts.id, wp_postmeta.meta_key, wp_postmeta.meta_value 
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.id=wp_postmeta.post_id 
WHERE wp_posts.post_type='foo' 
AND post_status='publish' 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key='some_key' 
OR wp_postmeta.meta_key='another_some_key' 
into outfile './export.csv' fields terminated by ';' lines terminated by '\n';
```

If you want to add some text before each column result use `CONCAT_WS()`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws

```
SELECT wp_posts.id, CONCAT_WS("_","a_key_from",wp_postmeta.meta_key) ,CONCAT_WS("_","a_value_from",meta_value)  
FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.id=wp_postmeta.post_id 
WHERE wp_posts.post_type='foo' 
AND post_status='publish' 
AND wp_postmeta.meta_key='some_key' 
OR wp_postmeta.meta_key='another_some_key' 
into outfile './export.csv' fields terminated by ';' lines terminated by '\n';
```

The second query result would look like:
[image]

Into `outfile` statement example:

[image]

Comment: I am gettiing `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'into outfile './export.csv' fields terminated by ';' lines terminated by '\n' LI' at line 8`

Comment: @MIA which query are you using?

Comment: I am getting the same error fot both query.

Comment: @MIA you have a `(` after your second `AND` i changed, try now and tell if it is working

Comment: now: `Unexpected ordering of clauses. (near "FROM" at position 67)`

Comment: @MIA your question was about exporting to CSV file not fixing your query. If you have a problem with your query please ask another question. I add another image to explain into outfile command

Comment: I am sorry if my question was not clear: `How to query a record that has many assoiated rows in onother table to be viewed as one row`. Mentioning the exporting to a csv is just to be clear about my case, but not my question. Thanks though.

Comment: @MIA you should provide, table description, some insert data, and what is your expected result. It will be good if you provide a dbfiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/31